# Laravel passport:install error: doesn't create oauth public and private keys

Tags: laravel, mongodb, vue.js, heroku

I'm working in a `Laravel` and `Vue.js` fullstack web app, with `MongoDB`. And I have some issues after deploying my app in `Heroku`, because of `laravel/passport`. Especially, when I want to login my users.

When I try to login the `POST` request return : `Error 500: Unable to read key` (and I have the same error with my localhost).

So I try a lot of things before asking this question, and followed the docs instructions of `laravel/passport`(https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport). In fact everything works except of this two commands (which are displaying the same exact error) :

```
>php artisan passport:install
>php artisan passport:keys --force
```

This error is :

```
ErrorException
file_put_contents(/secret-keys/oauth\oauth-public.key): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

And of course those commands doesn't create the key files (`oauth-private.key` & `oauth-public.key`) in my `storage` folder, that I need to login properly.

I have try this, but It doesn't solved my problem :

```
>composer install
>composer dump-autoload
>composer update --no-scripts
>composer update
>php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear
```

I have delete my `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file and run `composer install` too without solving my issue.

And finaly I have added this to my composer.json file :

```
"post-install-cmd": [ 
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "chmod -R 777 storage", 
        "php artisan passport:keys"
    ]
```

without again solving my problem.

What am I missing ? Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: which version of laravel are you using ?

Comment: Hi @workservice ! I'm using Laravel 7.